# Limit user to only submitting one list item

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, list

We are doing a raffle at work, and we want to make sure users aren't submitting list items (their name) over and over again to increase their chances of winning the raffle. We'd like to avoid having this be a manual process if at all possible. I tried using [this link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/39531/how-can-i-limit-user-to-only-enter-one-item-in-a-list) as it seemed like a really easy solution, but something with the indexing of the calculated value is causing me to get a technical error (I think, because it doesn't throw an error when I don't force a unique value, and when I don't enforce a unique value it doesn't make me index the field) thrown when trying to save the changes to the column.

I'm envisioning setting up a variable in a workflow, and the variable will be a counter of how many list items are submitted by a user. If the variable is greater than one, delete the list item that is being created. Is this possible to do? Am I over thinking it? I'm open for any solution that is simpler than this - just whatever it takes to restrict a user from spamming submissions.

Comment: Have you considered using a Survey instead? They can be configured to allow only one response per user.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a complex way to do it, but I know here at work people want to be absolutely sure raffles aren't gamed, and we do a lot of raffles as well. I don't care for the survey lists so I kind of built my own.

I have 2 lists. First list is the 'entry', open to everyone. 2nd list is the 'official' list, which has one item per person.

On item creation in the first list , a workflow runs that looks at the second list of 'official entries' to see if there is an entry for that person. If not, the workflow adds the new item. (This is done in an app step so it has higher security) It then deletes the current item in list1 so the list is always empty.

I restrict the second list permissions to only a few people.