# Allow Only One User to Submit SP Form

Tags: 2013, javascript, jquery, designer-workflow, custom-list

I know this should be able to be possible but do not know where to start.  I am working in sp13 and created a custom list. The custom list form I want users to be able to submit one form and not be able to submit another.

Is there a way for a user to submit only one form and sharepoint will stop them from submitting another? 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: After more research. Options available are creating event handler (doesn't work in my environrment) or survey.  Can these be the only options? Could a SP Designer workflow work?

Comment: This post may help: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/39531/how-can-i-limit-user-to-only-enter-one-item-in-a-list